# How to show dataset changes in datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataset

I have a code like below.
I a dataset and two tables in it. And there is a relation between those tables.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dtPerson = new DataTable("Persons");
DataTable dtBooks = new DataTable("Books");
ds.Tables.Add(dtPerson);
ds.Tables.Add(dtBooks);
dtPersons = LoadPersons();
dtBooks = LoadBooks();
ds.Relations.Add(new DataRelation("PersonBookRel",dtPersons.Columns["P_ID"],dtBooks.Columns["P_ID"]));

gridPersons.DataSource = ds;
gridPersons.DataMember = "Persons";
gridBooks.DataSource = ds;
gridBooks.DataMember = "Books";
```

The problem is that, when i add new row to dtPerson, gridPerson does not show new records.
Code is below.

```
DataRow row = dtPerson.NewRow();
row[0]  = "Joe";
row[1] = "Black"
row[2] = 18;
...
dtPerson.Rows.Add(row);
ds.AcceptChanges();
```

So what is the problem? How to solve it?

Comment: `gridBooks.DataSource = "Books";` looks wrong for me. I guess you mean `gridBooks.DataMember = "Books";`

Comment: Yes u are right. i have changed. Thanks...

Comment: This should work; are `LoadPersons()` and `LoadBooks()` doing anything funny? Could the Relation act up? It shouldn't.

Comment: Just an (obvious) afterthought: Since the new row is not saved to the DB, it will not show/disappear when/if you reload the DataTables.